# Trying to overlap two images and showing a overlapped imaged in a third image

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I am trying to overlap two local images and trying to show the overlapped one in third image.
I am using this code but simulator shows nothing.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    image1 = [[UIImage alloc]init];

    image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"];

    imageA = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image1];


    [self merge];

}

-(void)merge
{
  CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGPoint thumbPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
    imageview.image = imageA.image;
    [imageA.image drawAtPoint:thumbPoint];

    imageB = [[UIImage alloc]init];

    imageB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Favorites.png"];

    CGPoint starredPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [imageB drawAtPoint:starredPoint];

    UIImage *imageC = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    imageview.image = imageC;

    [self.view addSubview:imageview];

}
```

I can't figure out/don't know where i am making mistake.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: frame varied to images count in your program r use constant frame..?

Comment: Are you trying to blend the two images, or are you trying to add one image below the other.

Comment: not exactly blending what i am trying to do is overlapping an image on other. For more clearance like i have an image and i am editing it by adding hate on the base image

Comment: So you have one Big image like iPhone image and you want to be able to put a small image on top of it a smaller Favorites image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the code from every where except the below code in Merge.

```
-(void)merge
{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(0,0);
   // The second point has to be some where different than the first point, other wise, the second image will be above the first image, and you wont even know that the two images are there.
    CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(100,100);

    UIImage *imageOne = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
    [imageOne drawAtPoint:point1];



    UIImage *imageTwo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"];
  // If you want the above image to have some blending, then you can do some thing like below. 
  //  [imageTwo drawAtPoint:point2 blendMode:kCGBlendModeMultiply alpha:0.5];

    [imageTwo drawAtPoint:point2];


    UIImage *imageC = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,200,200)];
    iv.image=imageC;

    [self.view addSubview:iv];


}
```

Comment: thanks a ton man!!! well need a little more support....i want my 'imageTwo' to be drag dropped but here i am stuck how do i make only a partciular image to be movable...i wud really appreciate if u cud help me...thanks!!

Comment: You need to read up on some thing called Gesture Recognizers, if you want to be able to move a view which is already on the screen. I am assuming though, that your requirement is where you have a bucket of images and you should be able to drag and drop the second image on top of the first image. Even for that, you need to read up on Gesture recognizers. Once you do, show all of the child images as views then drag and drop each image on top. Let me know if you need additional help, but I am sure you will be able to figure it out.

Comment: hi @Srikanth I am stuck at one point while using the touch events here is the problem  **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761049/lower-the-cpu-usage-of-an-app**

Answer (score 0):

here's a general purpose "merge" function wrote as a UIImage category...  allows image overlay/underlay.

http://saveme-dot-txt.blogspot.com/2011/06/merge-image-function.html